# jQuery animate to run in steps

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I want to create an animation which looks like flashing lights.
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LwAVz/1/)

I want each div in each row to change color one by one.
But animate function is called in one go.
Please assist / guide me how can I do what I desire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me introduce you to a piece of magic called setInterval().  Start by reading here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval